# How do you access the correct object in a dynamic array using a textfields name and value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a dynamic array of values that i want to be able to change as I type and submit textfields. How do i properly change the value of the variable in the correct object of the array by submitting the textfields?

I have tried relating the key of the exercise to the values i need but its not working.

this is the parent function

```
export default class AddWorkoutForm extends Component {
    state = {
        step: 1,
        name: '',
        duration: 0,
        date: '',
        exerciselist: [
            {
                id: uuid.v4(),
                exerciseName: '',
                numberOfSets: 0,
                weight: 0,
                reps: 0
            }
        ],
    }

    // Generate Exercise objects in exerciselist
    addExercises = () => {
        this.setState({
            exerciselist: [
                ...this.state.exerciselist,
                {
                    id: uuid.v4(),
                    exerciseName: '',
                    numberOfSets: 0,
                    weight: 0,
                    reps: 0
                }
            ]
        })
    }

    // Remove exercise object in exerciselist
    removeExercises = (id) => {
        if (this.state.exerciselist.length > 1) {
            this.setState({
                exerciselist: [...this.state.exerciselist.filter(exercise => exercise.id !== id)]
            })
        }
    }

    // Proceed to next step
    nextStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step + 1
        });
    };

    // Go back to prev step
    prevStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step - 1
        });
    };

    // Handle fields change
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        const { step } = this.state;
        const { name, duration, date, exerciselist } = this.state;
        const values = { name, duration, date, exerciselist };
        switch (step) {
            case 1:
                return (
                    <AddWorkout
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        values={values}
                    />
                );
            case 2:
                return (
                    <AddExercise
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        prevStep={this.prevStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        addExercises={this.addExercises}
                        removeExercises={this.removeExercises}
                        values={values}
                    />
                );
            case 3:
                return (
                    <AddWorkoutConfirm
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        prevStep={this.prevStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        values={values}
                    />
                );
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for mapping the fields for each object in the dynamic array:

```
export default class AddExercise extends Component {

    continue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    }

    back = (e) => {
        this.props.prevStep();
    };

    render() {
        const { values, handleChange, addExercises, removeExercises } = this.props;
        const { exerciselist } = values;
        return (
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center", height: "100%" }}>
                <ClientMenuBar title="Add An Exercise" />
                <h2>Enter Your Exercise Details</h2>
                <form>
                    <div style={styles.form}>
                        {exerciselist.map((exercise) => {
                            return (
                                <div style={styles.textfieldWrapper} key={exercise.id}>
                                    <TextField
                                        fullWidth
                                        label="Exercise Name"
                                        margin="dense"
                                        name="exerciseName"
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        defaultValue={exercise.exerciseName}
                                    />
                                    <TextField
                                        label="Starting # Of Reps"
                                        margin="dense"
                                        type="number"
                                        style={styles.textfield}
                                        name="reps"
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        defaultValue={exercise.reps}
                                    />
                                    <TextField
                                        label="Starting Weight"
                                        margin="dense"
                                        type="number"
                                        style={styles.textfield}
                                        name="weight"
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        defaultValue={exercise.weight}
                                    />
                                    <TextField
                                        label="# of Sets"
                                        margin="dense"
                                        type="number"
                                        style={styles.textfield}
                                        name="numberOfSets"
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        defaultValue={exercise.numberOfSets}
                                    />
                                    <Button
                                        onClick={() => removeExercises(exercise.id)}
                                        size="small"
                                        disableRipple
                                        fullWidth
                                    >
                                        REMOVE EXERCISE
                                </Button>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                        <Button
                            onClick={addExercises}
                            size="small"
                            disableRipple
                            fullWidth
                        >
                            ADD EXERCISE
                    </Button>
                    </div>
                    <div style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
                        <Button
                            color="inherit"
                            variant="contained"
                            style={styles.button}
                            size="large"
                            onClick={this.back}
                        >
                            back
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            color="primary"
                            variant="contained"
                            style={styles.button}
                            size="large"
                            onClick={this.continue}
                        >
                            Next
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And this is where i am printing out what i have:

```
export default class AddWorkoutConfirm extends Component {

    continue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // PROCESS FORM //
        this.props.nextStep();
    };

    back = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    };

    render() {
        const { name, duration, date, exerciselist } = this.props.values;
        return (
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center", height: "100%" }}>
                <ClientMenuBar title="Confirm Your Details" />
                <h2>Enter Your Workout Details</h2>
                <form style={styles.form}>
                    <List>
                        <ListItem>Workout Name: {name}</ListItem>
                        <ListItem>Estimated Duration Of Workout: {duration} mins</ListItem>
                        <ListItem>Number Of Exercises: {exerciselist.length}</ListItem>
                        <ListItem>Date Of Workout: {date}</ListItem>
                    </List>
                    <div style={{borderTop:"1px solid gray"}}>
                        {
                            exerciselist.map((exercise) => {
                            return (
                                <List key={exercise.id}>
                                    <ListItem>Exercise Name: {exercise.exerciseName}</ListItem>
                                    <ListItem>Number of Sets: {exercise.numberOfSets}</ListItem>
                                    <ListItem>Starting Weight: {exercise.weight} lbs</ListItem>
                                    <ListItem>Starting Number Of Reps: {exercise.reps}</ListItem>
                                </List>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
                    <Button
                        color="inherit"
                        variant="contained"
                        style={styles.button}
                        size="large"
                        onClick={this.back}
                    >
                        back
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        color="primary"
                        variant="contained"
                        style={styles.button}
                        size="large"
                        onClick={this.continue}
                    >
                        Confirm
                    </Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

It properly prints out the values that are not in an array but i dont know how to use a handleChange for the values in the array. It's not recording what i am typing at all for the dynamic arrays values.

Comment: for your handler functions, just pass what you need through to give you that context. `onChange={handleChange.bind(this, exercise)}`. This will pass the exact exercise you are dealing with to the handler. Then you can update that exercise's values with new state updates

Comment: i changed that line, but it gave me: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. Am I missing something simple with what you said to do?

Comment: You have to update the handler function to accept that property.. you can't just set into state the way you are....

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see `handleChange` is triggered when there is change event on the `TextField`. Each TextField component represents an attribute of exercise in the `exerciselist` that is in your state. Now when user tries to add an exercise, you call the `handleChange` which sets in the state the value for `exerciseName` and same for other attributes. But when user clicks on a `Button` that adds the exercise, you are not constructing a new `exercise` object and adding it to your `exerciselist`. Instead your function `addExercises` below adds a default exercise object which has an auto generated uuid, and empty exerciseName, 0 numberOfSets, weight and reps. You need to pass the exerciseName, numberOfSets, weight, reps to this function that user entered on the form -> construct a new exercise object and then add that object to your `exerciseList` array in the state.

`

```
addExercises = () => {
  this.setState({
                exerciselist: [
                    ...this.state.exerciselist,
                    {
                        id: uuid.v4(),
                        exerciseName: '',
                        numberOfSets: 0,
                        weight: 0,
                        reps: 0
                    }
                ]
            })
        }`
```

Hope that helps!